# Custom Formula to look at a different GSheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, google-drive-api

I am still trying to wrap my head around using script, so my apologies if this is basic.

I have a summary Spreadsheet that pulls values from hundreds of other documents.  This used (too many) importrange formulas, but many of these are now #REF or ...Loading.

I am trying to create a custom formula that will mimic the importrange function and return the values.
I thought the hard part would be getting the formulas to update when another document was updated, but I have fallen right at the start.

This is my code.

```
function GetRngValue(ShtURL, GetRng) {
// find id from shtURL? - check if the workbook was updated in the last minute
Logger.log(ShtURL);
var Source = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(ShtURL);
// IF Source lastupdated > ThisSht lastupdated then  [ Ensure update runs at startup though ]
if (DriveApp.getFileById(Source.getId()).getLastUpdated() > DriveApp.getFileById(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()).getLastUpdated()) {
  
  var shtNm = GetRng.substring(1,find("!")-1);
  Logger.log(shtNm);
  var myRng = GetRng.substring(find("!")+1,len(GetRng));
  Logger.log(myRng);
  TargetRng =  Source.getSheetByName(shtNm)
  var TargetRng = Source.getSheetByName(shtNm).getRange("'"+myRng+"'").getValues;
  Logger.log(TargetRng);
  return TargetRng;
 };
 Logger.log("First - "+DriveApp.getFileById(Source.getId()).getLastUpdated()+" meets last - "+DriveApp.getFileById(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()).getLastUpdated());
Logger.log("Ending");

}
```

I am getting the error:
Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets (line 4).

The formula in the cell is: =GetRngValue("""https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1axNelBTg4j..etc..7xJx2lSk/edit""", """Summary!B32""")
Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Can I not reference another GSheet from a custom formula?

Comment: *Can I not reference another GSheet from a custom formula?* Yup. There is a twisted workaround with service accounts, but you're better off using custom functions for what it is intended for and use menus/buttons/trigggers instead

Comment: Thanks for your reply TheMaster.  Totally random, but if I were to set up a trigger to look at all the cells containing an importrange formula, is there a way that I could set the displayed value without overwriting the formula underneath?

Comment: No. But why? Formulas are formulas and scripts are scripts. Don't mix them. Use scripts only to get data from different sheets and set them to sheet.

Comment: I think i've finally gone mad.  Each row relates to a different property (with its own Gsheet) and each column is for a different cell (all non-contiguous).  If I enter the value then I lose the cell and Sheet link.  I've stopped thinking.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [TheMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8404453/themaster), you're better off without custom functions here. They place a lot more restrictions and are slower than if your spreadsheet were updated via script–replacing your `IMPORTRANGE()` functions with `GetRngValue()` wouldn't help you much if it were even possible. If you're pulling "values from hundreds of other documents", then it's likely you're well due for an overhaul anyway.

In the [documentation for custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services), it's stated that "custom functions never ask users to authorize access to personal data". This includes spreadsheet data and is later made more explicit:

> Cannot open other spreadsheets (**SpreadsheetApp.openById()** or **SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl()**).

Comment: Thanks Diego.  This is a Sheet summarising property data, but I had nothing to do with it before Friday.  Then they asked me to add some Charts.  These didn't work because of the errors.

Comment: @GlibGibon Try changing any value in the IMPORTRANGE() and then returning it to the original formula. This should force it to be re-executed and I faintly recall it resolving prior issues for me.

Comment: I have changed the Cell Letters from Uppercase to lowercase, removed the = to leave the text, then put it back in - there are hundreds that just stay at #REF or ...loading.  I am not sure if some limit has been exceeded but they aren't refreshing.  Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: Could you share the link so we can see how is the Sheet looking like?